# In-App-Billing v3 проблема с "consume" контентом

Tags: android, in-app-purchases

Привет!

Реализовал в своем приложении отключение рекламы на базе библиотеки с [GitHub: "anjlab/android-inapp-billing-v3"](https://github.com/anjlab/android-inapp-billing-v3). Все работает отлично. Теперь появилась надобность реализовать покупку "заканчиваемых" / "consume" плюшек в приложении. Обратился к этой же библиотеке. Прочел `readme` и добавил следующий код в класс:

```
bp.consumePurchase(myProductId);
```

Но результат всегда `false`. Посмотрел в `issues`, проблема есть, разработчик библиотеки пока никак не отреагировал. Решил задать вопрос здесь.

Comment: Вот вам ссылка на класс `BillingProcessor`: https://github.com/anjlab/android-inapp-billing-v3/blob/master/library/src/main/java/com/anjlab/android/iab/v3/BillingProcessor.java    Вы сами можете посмотреть, что происходит при вызове `consumePurchase`. А теперь вопрос: вам в лог ошибки сыплются при этом?

Comment: @metalurgus, нет (лог по тегу: iabv3).

Comment: @metalurgus, класс BillingProcessor я просматривал ранее, видел, что ошибка из-за инициализации, но у меня инициализация есть. Если я не инициализировал связь, то не смог был работать с подписками и покупками, которые контролирует Google. Проблема только с исчерпывающим контентом.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как нужно это все сделать:

Когда нужно купить повторно что-то, то пишем так:

```
 // #1
 bp.consumePurchase(item_Id);
 // #2
 bp.purchase( `Your_Context_Here` , item_Id);
```

- 1: "говорим" `Google`, что покупки ранее не было.
- 2: покупаем `item_Id` заново.

**!!!** Естественно, перед пунктом 1 идет инициализация/реализация всей `Billing` логики.

Comment: Здравствуйте! Не могли бы вы показать всю реализацию отключения рекламы? Что то я запутался совсем с этой библиотекой в методе восстановления и.тд.

Comment: @RuslanChepizhko, да, конечно. Вы можете создать отдельный вопрос, я дам Вам ответ в виде кода.

Comment: я создал вопрос по библиотеке

Comment: Я создал отдельный вопрос.

Comment: @RuslanChepizhko, ответ готов: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/770241/22239

Comment: @web_alex, Здравствуйте, не подскажете,как проверить статус покупки? Не была ли она отменена? К примеру, с помощью возврата.  Нехорошо получается, пользователь вернул средства и пользуется платным контентом

Comment: @КириллЖелнов, Здравствуйте! Просто при старте приложения проверяйте наличие покупки. Если сервер Google Billing говорит, что не покупался товар, то закрываем доступ, иначе все ок. То есть ответ от сервера ВСЕГДА в приоритете, чем то, что сохранено внутри приложения. Да, хитрый людей хватает!

Comment: @web_alex, что-то такой подход ничего не дал. Все равно пишет "Произошла техническая ошибка". Или это проблема в чем то другом?