# Библиотека Android In-App Billing v3 Library

Tags: android, in-app-purchases

Реализовал в своем приложении отключение рекламы на базе библиотеки с GitHub: "anjlab/android-inapp-billing-v3".

```
public class HelpActivity extends Activity implements BillingProcessor.IBillingHandler{
    ScrollView scrollView;


    TextView mTextView;
    BillingProcessor bp;
    static final String Off_ADVERTISING = "off_advertising";
    String fileName = "data";
    boolean m_off_advertising = false;
    SharedPreferences sPref;



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_help);
        // Убираем панель уведомлений
        this.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        scrollView = (ScrollView)findViewById(R.id.scrollView);


        try {
            readFileXML();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        mTextView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView11);

//        String licenseKey = getResources().getString(R.string.license_key);
//        bp = new BillingProcessor(this, licenseKey, this);
        bp = new BillingProcessor(this, null, this);

        mTextView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @SuppressLint("ShowToast")
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
               // bp.purchase(HelpActivity.this, "off_advertising");
                bp.purchase(HelpActivity.this, "android.test.purch");
            }
        });
        if(m_off_advertising){
            //показываем рекламу
            mTextView.setText("не показываем рекламу");

        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onProductPurchased(@NonNull String productId, @Nullable TransactionDetails details) {

        mTextView.setText("Реклама убрана");
        m_off_advertising = true;
        saveData();
    }

    @Override
    public void onPurchaseHistoryRestored() {

//        mTextView.setText("Реклама восстановлена");
//        m_off_advertising = true;
//        saveData();
    }

    @Override
    public void onBillingError(int errorCode, @Nullable Throwable error) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onBillingInitialized() {

    }
    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (!bp.handleActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)) {
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        saveData();
        super.onPause();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {

        try {
            readFileXML();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        super.onResume();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        saveData();
        if (bp != null) {
            bp.release();
        }
        super.onDestroy();
    }


    void readFileXML() throws IOException {
        this.sPref = getSharedPreferences(this.fileName, 0);
        this.m_off_advertising = this.sPref.getBoolean(Off_ADVERTISING, false);

    }


    void saveData() {
        //Log.d(TAG, "m_off_advertising save " + this.m_off_advertising);
        this.sPref = getSharedPreferences(this.fileName, 0);
        SharedPreferences.Editor ed = this.sPref.edit();
        ed.putBoolean(Off_ADVERTISING, this.m_off_advertising);
        ed.commit();
    }


}
```

Но есть 2 но:
Первое: 
После покупки, нужно ещё раз нажать на текст купить, чтобы покупка отобразилась.
Второе:
Метод восстановления срабатывает всегда, и выполняет всё что в нём написано, не проверяя id продукта

```
 @Override
    public void onPurchaseHistoryRestored() {

//        mTextView.setText("Реклама восстановлена");
//        m_off_advertising = true;
//        saveData();
    }
```

Как можно сделать проверку при включении и восстановлении для определённого продукта?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Как я у себя реализовал отключение рекламы в приложении с применением библиотеки [Android In-App-Billing-v3 от AnjLab](https://github.com/anjlab/android-inapp-billing-v3)?

1. файл **`build.gradle`** модуля `/app`

```
dependencies {
    // Ваши всевозможные библиотеки
    // ...
    compile 'com.anjlab.android.iab.v3:library:1.0.44'
    // ...
    // Ваши всевозможные библиотеки

    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

**следите за последней release версией библиотеки**, если нет возможности заходить на GitHub страничку и выписывать номер версии оттуда, то можно сделать следующее:

1. `compile 'com.anjlab.android.iab.v3:library:+'`
2. данная строчка будет выделена `Android Studio`, ставим курсор слева от `+`
3. Жмем `Alt + Enter`, выбираем `Replace with specific version`

Идем дальше ...

2. класс **`SettingsFrag`**

Мое приложение работает по принципу "В одной `Activity` отображаю все  `Fragment`'ы."

```
package com.my_best_of_the_best_application_name.ui.fragment;

// список **import**'ов ...

public class SettingsFrag extends Fragment implements BillingProcessor.IBillingHandler {

    private boolean adsStatus;    // храним текущий статус отображения рекламы
    private boolean initialize;   // храним готовность к покупкам
    private BillingProcessor bp;  // переменная нашего процессора

    private PreferencesManager prefManager; // класс, который работает с SharedPreferences. Я для себя решил вынести всю логику отдельно
    private Resources resources;            // для работы с ресурсами. Раз получаем и постоянно обращаемся
    private ToggleButton tbAdsState;        // кнопка

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);
        this.mContext = context;         
        bp = new BillingProcessor(context,
                InAppBillingResources.getRsaKey(), InAppBillingResources.getMerchantId(), this); // инициализируем `BillingProcessor`. В документации на `GitHub` сказано, что для защиты от липовых покупок через приложения типа `freedom` необходимо в конструктор `BillingProcessor`'а передать еще и свой `MERCHANT_ID`. Где его взять - внизу текущего ответа опишу шаги
        prefManager = new PreferencesManager(context); // класс, который работает с `SharedPreferences`
        adsStatus = prefManager.getAdsStatus();        // получаем из `SharedPreferences` сохраненное состояние рекламы (ВКЛ / ВЫКЛ)
        resources = context.getResources();            // получаем "доступ" к ресурсам
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // создаем `View` экрана настроек 
        View settView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.frag_sett_screen, container, false);

        // инициализация других полей
        tbAdsState = (ToggleButton) settView.findViewById(R.id.tbAdsState);
        // инициализация других полей

        // вешаем слушателя нажатий по кнопке `ToggleButton`
        tbAdsState.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                // `adsStatus` : getAdsStatus из класса `PreferencesManager`
                // true - enabled (ВКЛ)  | false - disabled (ВЫКЛ)
                if (adsStatus && initialize) {
                    bp.purchase(getActivity(), InAppBillingResources.getSKU_Disable_Ads());
                }

                if (!adsStatus) {
                    tbAdsState.setChecked(false);
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(),
                            getActivity().getResources().getString(R.string.txt_ads_is_already_disabled),
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }

            }
        });

        return settView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        tbAdsState.setChecked(prefManager.getAdsStatus());
    }

    // диалог, который скажет пользователю, что после покупки необходимо перезагрузиться
    private void restartDialog() {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder;

        View alertLayout = View.inflate(mContext, R.layout.dialog_restart, null);
        builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext, R.style.AppThemeDialogStyleDark);

        builder.setTitle(resources.getString(R.string.msg_notification_Title));
        builder.setView(alertLayout);
        builder.setCancelable(false);

        builder.setPositiveButton(resources.getString(R.string.ans_restart),
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        restartApp();
                    }
                });

        builder.show();
    }

    // перезагружаем приложение
    private void restartApp() {
        Intent rIntent = mContext.getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage(mContext.getPackageName());
        if (rIntent != null) {
            rIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
            mContext.startActivity(rIntent);
        }
    }

    // ... другие методы класса
    // [START billing part of class]

    @Override
    public void onProductPurchased(@NonNull String productId, TransactionDetails details) {
        // Called when requested PRODUCT ID was successfully purchased
        // Вызывается, когда запрашиваемый PRODUCT ID был успешно куплен

        if (bp.isPurchased(productId)) {
            prefManager.setAdsStatus(false); // 1. записываем в `SharedPreferences` состояние рекламы (ВЫКЛ / false)
            tbAdsState.setChecked(false);    // 2. устанавливаем `TogglButton` в соответствующее состояние
            restartDialog(); // 3. перезагружаем приложение
        } else {
            tbAdsState.setChecked(true); // иначе, если не прошла покупка, оставляем состояние (ВКЛ / true)
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onPurchaseHistoryRestored() {
        //Вызывается, когда история покупки была восстановлена,
        // и список всех принадлежащих идентификаторы продуктов был загружен из Google Play

        // случай #2 (см. ниже)
    }

    @Override
    public void onBillingError(int errorCode, Throwable error) {
        // Вызывается, когда появляется ошибка. См. константы класса
        // для получения более подробной информации
    }

    @Override
    public void onBillingInitialized() {
        // Вызывается, когда bp был инициализирован и он готов приобрести
        initialize = true;
    }
    // [END billing part of class]

}
```

**класс `InAppBillingResources`**

```
public class InAppBillingResources {

    private static final String RSA_KEY = "GFGFD156GF1SDF1.... FDS156DS"; // Ваш `RSA` ключ из `Google Play Developer Console`
    private static final String MERCHANT_ID = "16..1511.5..82";           // Ваш `MERCHANT_ID` из `Google Play Developer Console`
    private static final String SKU_DISABLE_ADS = "disable_ads";          // Ваш `product_id`, создается в `Google Play Developer Console`


    public static String getRsaKey() {
        return RSA_KEY;
    }

    public static String getMerchantId() {
        return MERCHANT_ID;
    }

    public static String getSKU_Disable_Ads() {
        return SKU_DISABLE_ADS;
    }
}
```

**класс `PreferencesManager`**

```
public class PreferencesManager {

    private static SharedPreferences mSPref;
    private SharedPreferences.Editor mSPEditor;

    private static final String APP_PREF    = "app_pref";      // имя файла настроек Вашего приложения

    private static final String APP_ADS_STATUS = "adsStatus";  // статус рекламы

    public PreferencesManager(Context context) {
        mSPref = context.getSharedPreferences(APP_PREF, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    }

    public void setAdsStatus(boolean adsStatus) {
        // true - enabled  | false - disabled
        mSPEditor = mSPref.edit();
        mSPEditor.putBoolean(APP_ADS_STATUS, adsStatus);
        mSPEditor.apply();
    }

    public boolean getAdsStatus() {
        return mSPref.getBoolean(APP_ADS_STATUS, true);
    }

}
```

**Дополнительная полезная информация**

1. Где взять в `Google Play Developer Console` свой `RSA` ключ - [Читать Google Справку](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/186113?hl=ru)
2. Где взять в `Google Play Developer Console` свой `MERCHANT_ID` - [Читать Google Справку](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/7163092?hl=ru)
3. Метод **восстановлен**ия. Вы можете реализовать восстановление покупок на **стартовом** activity приложения. Код инициализации `BillingProcessor` такой же. Метод **`onPurchaseHistoryRestored`** ниже

```
@Override
    public void onPurchaseHistoryRestored() {
        //Вызывается, когда история покупки была восстановлена,
        // и список всех принадлежащих идентификаторы продуктов был загружен из Google Play

        // так Вы сможете НУЖНУЮ покупку проверить
        for (String sku : bp.listOwnedProducts()) {
            MyAppLogs.show("Owned Managed Product: " + sku);
            boolean wasBouhtg = sku.equals(InAppBillingResources.getSKU_Disable_Ads());
            if (wasBouhtg) {
                // true - куплено
                // пишем в `SharedPreferences`, что отключили рекламу
            } else {
                // false - не куплено
                // пишем в `SharedPreferences`, что нужно показывать рекламу
            }
        }
    }
```

// Если где-то я что-то упустил, сообщите, пожалуйста, в комментарии к моему ответу

Comment: Огромное Спасибо! Всё очень доходчиво!

Comment: @RuslanChepizhko, рад был помочь Вам! Успехов Вам в разработке персонального приложения! ;-)

Comment: Спасибо) И вам Удачи!

Comment: Не совсем понятно. Например как выглядит экран настроек R.layout.frag_sett_screen?

Comment: @Artsait, как Вам удобно, так и будет выглядеть. Главное, чтобы в разметке была ToggleButton с id "tbAdsState"

Comment: Реклама у меня в файле Ads.java

Добавляю ее так.     
  Ads.showBanner(this);

Comment: ToggleButton я так понял это просто кнопка?

Comment: Простите, Нажимаю Enter,  чтобы с новой строки написать, но он публикует комментарий, не успеваю мысль полностью выразить))

Comment: @Artsait, нет ToggleButton - кнопка, совмещенная с переключателем (https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/togglebutton.html). Да, Enter = опубликовать. Поэтому нужно писать сплошняком и без переносов.

Comment: Я наверно слишком тупой. Подскажи пожалуйста куда все таки засунуть код отображение рекламы         Ads.showBanner(this); ? И есть где нибудь пример с этим кодоб например на гитхабе?

Comment: Есть и на GitHub пример, есть и на ru.stackoverflow. Сначала попробуйте поискать здесь. Если не найдете, то можете задать вопрос, я Вам помогу.

Comment: Создал вопрос, как будет время посмотрите пожалуйста. Может Вы сможете понять https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/774993/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BF%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%BB%D1%8E%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%BC%D1%8B-%D1%81-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%89%D1%8C%D1%8E-in-app

Comment: <b>web_alex<b>,а что за имя файла настроек Вашего приложения в классе PreferencesManager?точнее,где его взять это имя файла?

Comment: @devnull, самому придумать нужно. Или использовать вариант по умолчанию, но я его в примере не рассматривал. Обычно в проектах даю свое имя.

Comment: @web_alex, Гугл рекомендует RSA_KEY хранить от посторонних глаз. Не подскажете как это можно сделать? Пробовал ProGuard, но он не трогает этот код и его можно легко получить. Спасибо.

Comment: @dubok79, можно в build.gradle положить

Comment: @web_alex, а как именно это делается можете показать пример? Спасибо.